# Chart.JS TypeError: this.scale is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I am just trying to plot some basic X and Y points on a line graph being gathered from some PHP.

On a form submit I do a ajax post to get the points for the graph. Then run a JS function which should create the graph. I keep getting "this.scale is undefined" and the graph shows nothing/crashes.

```
HTML 
<canvas id="cv" height="50"></canvas>
```

EDIT:

This is the JSON being set in PHP being sent back from the post.
The $dates is just the below dates same with $num_added is the below data points.

```
    $ds['labels'] = $dates;
    $ds['datasets'][]=array('label' => $tid,'fillColor' => 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)','strokeColor' =>'rgba(220,220,220,1)','pointColor' => 'rgba(220,220,220,1)','pointStrokeColor' => '#fff','pointHighlightFill' => '#fff','pointHighlightStroke' => 'rgba(220,220,220,1)','data' => $num_added);
    print json_encode($ds);
```

Ajax post which returns the JSON object of

```
{
"labels":[ "2016-01-10","2016-01-12","2016-01-13","2016-01-14","2016-01-15","2016-01-16","2016-01-17","2016-01-18","2016-01-19","2016-01-21","2016-01-22","2016-01-24","2016-01-26","2016-01-27","2016-01-29","2016-01-30","2016-01-31","2016-02-01","2016-02-02","2016-02-03","2016-02-04","2016-02-05","2016-02-06","2016-02-07","2016-02-08","2016-02-10"],
"datasets":[
{
   "label":"XYZ",
   "fillColor":"rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
   "strokeColor":"rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   "pointColor":"rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   "pointStrokeColor":"#fff",
   "pointHighlightFill":"#fff",
   "pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   "data":["1483","2044","834","818","1215","1534","823","1368","3048","4808","4486","6488","1340","4260","1863","5309","1259","858","4041","7444","4514","3994","3574","1419","1383","1825"]
}
]}
```

This is the same format of the example the give you online which is why I am stumped in figuring this out

Once I get the points I sent them to my js function line_graph("cv",data) to graph the line but this is where it crashes. Which doesnt make sense to me because I got it right from thr documentation.

```
function line_graph(holder, data){

Chart.defaults.global.animation = true;
Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 60;
Chart.defaults.global.animationEasing = "easeOutQuart";
Chart.defaults.global.showScale = true;
Chart.defaults.global.scaleOverride = false;
Chart.defaults.global.scaleLineColor ="rgba(0,0,0,.1)";
Chart.defaults.global.scaleLineWidth = 1;
Chart.defaults.global.scaleShowLabels = true;
Chart.defaults.global.scaleLabel = "<%=value%>";
Chart.defaults.global.scaleIntegersOnly = true;
Chart.defaults.global.scaleBeginAtZero = false;
Chart.defaults.global.scaleFontFamily = "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif";
Chart.defaults.global.scaleFontSize = 12;
Chart.defaults.global.scaleFontStyle = "normal";
Chart.defaults.global.scaleFontColor = "#666";
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = true;
Chart.defaults.global.showTooltips = true;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipEvents = ["mousemove", "touchstart", "touchmove"];
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFillColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFontFamily = "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFontSize = 14;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFontStyle = "normal";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFontColor = "#fff";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipTitleFontFamily = "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipTitleFontSize = 14;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipTitleFontStyle = "bold";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipTitleFontColor = "#fff";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipYPadding = 6;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipXPadding = 6;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipCaretSize = 8;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipCornerRadius = 6;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipXOffset = 10;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipTemplate = "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>";
Chart.defaults.global.multiTooltipTemplate = "<%= value %>";

var ctx = document.getElementById(holder).getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
scaleShowGridLines : true,
scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
scaleGridLineWidth : 1,
scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
bezierCurve : true, 
bezierCurveTension : 0.4,
pointDot : true,
pointDotRadius : 4,
pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,
pointHitDetectionRadius : 20,
datasetStroke : true,
datasetStrokeWidth : 2,
datasetFill : true,
legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
});

}
```

The graph works if i just hard code the data into the function but obviously that's worthless. I have literally tried everything I can think of so I figure someone may have run into this problem. Its a simple ajax to get the data and then display the points which is annoying because its a simple process. I know I am just missing somthing this being my first time with chart.js

Comment: Do a alert(data.datasets[0].label) in the 1st line of the function. If you get an error, you are not intepreting your JSON right.

Comment: I am getting that it is undefined. I am going to upload how I am setting my JSON. Do you think you could take a quick look?

Comment: is data undefined too? because you'll probably need something of the sort  `print ("var data = " . json_encode($ds));`

Comment: No data is fine. Its the returned JSON from the POST. But it keeps saying .datasets is undefined which makes me think the php that creates the object has something wrong with it

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out after about 2 days. Its pretty annoying but I guess it was looking at the JSON as an array and not the object it needed. so i did a parseJson on the returned data and it worked perfectly into the graph....Any way thanks for your help you telling me to do that alert @potatopeelings helped me realize the JSON was not being read properly.